# Wix toolset - Set Property on DoAction or Property Control Event with RegistrySearch

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

In my installer, I schedule a property to be set with the value of a registry key easily enough. What I would like to do is run that registry search and set the property on a button press (because it might change after the installer has initialized), and then use that value in my control flow. Furthermore, I'd like to try to do this without a full-blown DLL custom action. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14313186/wix-can-not-search-registry-with-key-is-property-which-is-set-from-setproperty) stack overflow question, a commenter seems to imply that this is possible, but I haven't managed to get it to work.

Something like:

```
<Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" 
         Control="RemoveButton" 
         Property="DEPLOYMENTS" 
         Value="[RegSearchDeploymentsExist]">
    1
</Publish>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should set a property element in the mainpart of the installer, after the product tag, or if you have a media tag, after that. The "value" attribute should set in these property else. And why do you have the attribute "control" in the publish element?

Comment: As you can see here: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd%5Cwix%5Cpublish.html the Control attribute is perfectly valid. Thanks for the attempt, but I already know how to set a property at the startup of an installer package, and that's not what my question is asking.